# Save image in database

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app,User can add templates. On this template he adds any number of images & text views.
He has option to change textviews properties like font name, font color,font size & many more.
Image operations like rotate image to any angle,increase / decrease size at runtime and many more. After doing this, user saves this template & see later he wants.
So I want to store this all operation perform by user & view on recent list.
So How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite3 *database;
    dbName=@"dataTable.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentdir=[documentpath objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath=[documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
   if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Name:%@,Company:%@,URL:%@",model.personName,model.companyName,model.imgurl);
        const char *insertSQL="insert into Persons(PersonName,CompanyName,ImgUrl,PersonImage)values(?,?,?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,insertSQL, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,1,[model.personName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,2,[model.companyName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,3,[model.imgurl UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStmt, 4, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);
        NSLog(@"Prepare");
        sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
    }
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to save in your db the **key to retrieve image** from disk.
After that, use `NSArchiver` and `NSUnarchiver` to get images from disk.

```
UIImage *img = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:db.ImgKey];
```

Saving images in db is heavy and discorages and heavy.

hope this helps.